# Telemetry vs Organization Insights for Monitoring

Tags: azure, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, azure-application-insights, telemetry

Dynamics CRM 365 Online has Telemetry to monitor application performance and usage. My understanding is it stores data in Azure by sending via Script and on this Alerts can be set in Azure.

There is a CRM solution Organization Insight which is used for counters like API faults etc. my understanding is that this solution stores data in CRM and not Azure.

Please help if this solution generated data can also be used for settings alerts in azure and if yes, how? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Over a period of time different products, SaaS offerings, platform tools, O365 capability were introduced/evolving in and around the Telemetry space. Some are strong in broader horizontal features vs deeper vertical strengths. Upto you to decide based on functionality matrix.

[Dynamics CRM using Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-sample-mscrm) - this is just leveraging Azure Application Insights to track Availability, Performance, Usage of our CRM online using AppInsights features. It gives you the power to utilize client side telemetry like user activities/metrics/exceptions/browser, Server side agent for on-premise logs similar to Event viewer/IIS logs, data export, Alerting mechanism & web hooks, custom query, visualizations inside Azure portal resources blade (slice/dice), predictive analysis, etc.

[CRM in-house Organization Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/admin/use-organization-insights-solution-view-instance-metrics) - this is inbuilt telemetry solution from Product team, not yet fully delivered (still with bugs & limited functionality for data consumption itself), but we can expect more features, options & utilities to explore more in future. **These are missing today & thats what you are asking**. You can download data, call MS to give you the exported data, but still Alerts & monitoring wont fit using only available odata support for charts. This covers a lot of useful Admin stuffs, like natively gives you all plugins, WF, API calls, user interactions, mailbox, storage data, etc within CRM.

[Activity logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/admin/enable-use-comprehensive-auditing) - this is in preview and MS saying it’s more than what we have in Audit today, gives you extra than CRM audit but less than what Org Insights providing, even less than AppInsights features. But I expect more functionalities here like Alerts, Monitoring, web hooks as this is across O365 platforms & available for Global admins.